# Regex to pick values from specific json key

Tags: json, go

My json string:

```
{
    "computed_at": "2022-11-29T08:21:47.904741+00:00",
    "data":
    {
        "2022-11-07":
        {
            "steps":
            [
                {
                    "count": 1853,
                    "avg_time": null,
                    "avg_time_from_start": null,
                    "session_event": "start",
                    "goal": "start",
                    "step_label": "Came to Corporate",
                    "overall_conv_ratio": 1,
                    "step_conv_ratio": 1
                },
                {
                    "count": 741,
                    "avg_time": 25451,
                    "avg_time_from_start": 25451,
                    "time_buckets_from_prev":
                    {
                        "lower": 0,
                        "higher": 0,
                        "buckets":
                        [
                            720,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            1,
                            0,
                            2,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0
                        ]
                    },
                    "time_buckets_from_start":
                    {
                        "lower": 0,
                        "higher": 0,
                        "buckets":
                        [
                            720,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4,
                            3,
                            3,
                            3,
                            1,
                            0,
                            2,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0
                        ]
                    },
                    "event": "Viewed Collection Page",
                    "goal": "Viewed Collection Page",
                    "step_label": "Viewed Collection Page",
                    "overall_conv_ratio": 0.39989206691851054,
                    "step_conv_ratio": 0.39989206691851054
                },
                {
                    "count": 174,
                    "avg_time": 53538,
                    "avg_time_from_start": 110700,
                    "time_buckets_from_prev":
                    {
                        "lower": 0,
                        "higher": 0,
                        "buckets":
                        [
                            163,
                            2,
                            1,
                            3,
                            0,
                            2,
                            1,
                            2,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0
                        ]
                    },
                    "time_buckets_from_start":
                    {
                        "lower": 0,
                        "higher": 0,
                        "buckets":
                        [
                            151,
                            4,
                            2,
                            5,
                            1,
                            4,
                            3,
                            3,
                            0,
                            1,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0
                        ]
                    },
                    "event": "Product Viewed",
                    "goal": "Product Viewed",
                    "step_label": "Product Viewed",
                    "overall_conv_ratio": 0.09390178089584458,
                    "step_conv_ratio": 0.23481781376518218
                }
            ],
            "analysis":
            {
                "completion": 174,
                "starting_amount": 1853,
                "steps": 3,
                "worst": 2
            }
        }
    },
    "meta":
    {
        "dates":
        [
            "2022-11-07"
        ],
        "property_values":
        [],
        "min_sampling_factor": 1,
        "group_by_metadata":
        []
    },
    "min_sampling_factor": 1
}
```

I want to extract the values for these particular keys (each of which has 3 instances in the above json string):

`count`
`step_conv_ratio`

What is the correct regex so that I will get `1853, 741, 174` for `count`; and `1, 0.39989206691851054, 0.23481781376518218` for `step_conv_ratio`?

Unmarshalling this to a Go struct is not ideal, since it has dynamic json field name, so I cannot use a static struct with static json tag to unmarshal. Hence I'm thinking of using regex.

Comment: *"since it has dynamic json field name, so I cannot use a static struct"* -- Use a map/struct combo. And in cases where that doesn't suffice, you can still use custom unmarshaling. Both options are more ideal than regexp.

Comment: I agree with @mkopriva. 
To parse only specific parts of the json you could use a lib like [gabs](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the comments about unmarshalling. Else the regex you are looking for is:

```
`"count": ([0-9]+)|"step_conv_ratio": ([0-9.]+)`
```

then the number will be in the second or the third element of the slice that contains the matches (e.g. after `FindAllStringSubmatch()`) depending on it's a `count` or a `step_conv_ratio`.